# Call a python function using os.system

Tags: python, os.system

I am calling a function, `func_1.py`, from my main one (`func.py`) using

```
import os
cmd = 'python func_1.py [x y t]'
os.system(cmd)
```

`x`, `y` and `t` are defined before in `func.py`.

`func_1.py` starts with `def the_reader(index, x, y, peak_number):`. When I run `func.py` I don't have problem compiling, but `func_1.py` doesn't do what expected. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are doing this instead of `import func_1`?

Comment: Even though `x`, `y` and `t` are defined as variables, what you pass to `func_1` is just that string. Maybe you should try `'func_1.py %r %r %r' % (x, y, t)`?

Comment: I am doing this to avoid a memory leak

Comment: @albus_c: Then tell us about the memory leak instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only pass in strings into the system command. You are passing the command line parameter "[x y t]". You have to extract the variables before the command.
I believe that your statement on the command line == python func_1.py [x y t] # No values just "[x y t]"

```
import os
cmd = "python func_1.py " + str(x) +" "+ str(y) +" "+ str(t)
os.system(cmd)
```